# Why cmd is closing when I enter this " dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli" command?

Tags: android, windows, flutter, firebase, command-prompt

Why command prompt is closing when I enter this command:-
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli ?

I'm trying to connect to firebase with my flutter app but when I enter this command in command prompt ..it closes.

Command:-

dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli